# How to capture enter key in DataGridView CellContentClick 

Tags: c#, winforms, keyevent

How to capture the `enter key` in DataGridView.CellContentClick in c#

Answer (score 1):

only the `spacebar` is handled, so you have to capture the `KeyUp event` on the cell first and raise the CellContentClick *if you want that*.

```
private void cell_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // modify/cast/transform e here to DataGridViewCellEventArgs
        dataGridView_CellContentClick(sender, e) 
    }
}
```